# Visio Web Part error Entry point not found

Tags: visio-services

I have sharepoint 2013 server and I am trying to publish some Visio drawings into the Visio Web Part. It's giving me this error:

> system.entrypointnotfoundexception: entry point was not found

I have tried uploading the Visio file in both 2010 and 2013 formats with no luck.

Answer (score 3):

The issue has been resolved, "Visio Graphics Service" on Sharepoint server was not running, which was causing this problem. Starting the service resolved it.